# Chef: Attributes with environments and databags

Tags: chef-infra

I don't quite figure out how to populate my attributes into my cookbook.

I'm able to get what are they for... nevertheless I'm trying to use `environments` and `data bags`.

My `data bags` are like:

```
{
  "id": "aws",
  {
    "dev": {"access_key": "XXX", "secret_key": "YYY"},
    "qa": {"access_key": "RRR", "secret_key": "TTT"},
    "prod": {"access_key": "PPP", "secret_key": "DDD"}
  }
}
```

So, in order to get the aws keys in order to get access to aws services I'm using this:

```
aws = data_bag_item('db','aws');
```

So, I'm able to write something like that in order to get cookbook "settings" according to current environment:

```
default['aws']['access_key'] = aws[node.chef_environment]
```

Nevertheless, I've written this sentence into my attributes files, and I'm getting `node_bag_item` is not available.

1. Why amn't I able to use this method?
2. Which default attributes' values should I set then?

Comment: Have a look here, these articles will explain all, if not most, of you attribute and data bag questions: [data bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html) and [attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html). Attributes evaluation order table is especially handy.

Answer (score 0):

Data bags have nothing to do with attributes and using them like that is unsafe. Data bags are a bit of a hammer in search of a nail, but they are mostly for non-node-specific data that you want to store somewhere outside of the cookbook versioning system. More specifically in this case, the `data_bag_item` DSL method is only available in recipe code, not attributes. Storing secrets in node attributes is a major footgun because they get saved back up to the Chef Server after the run is over.

tl;dr this is not a thing, watch https://coderanger.net/talks/secrets/ for more info on managing secrets in an automated infra.